# Database Table Row Counts Where Column Value is True

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to modify this query to give me the row counts for each table in the database where the table contains the column "Archive" and the total row counts along with the row count where "Archive = 1".  I've got the first part down but I'm having a brain fart with  the second part.

```
SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
 FROM sys.tables ta
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
 WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
 AND OBJECT_NAME(pa.object_id) IN 
 (
       --Criteria 1
   SELECT iq.TABLE_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS iq
   WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Archive%'
 )
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Stick a case statement inside your count. . . though if you're querying over all tables, you'll need to do some dynamic SQL to cater for the different table schemas.

Comment: @JohnLBevan That would work but i'm not sure of the syntax would I use table or schema ?  case when ta.(schema).column ?

Comment: True - I'd misread your question as just wanting there to be one archive column, rather than looking at all rows in all tables featuring an archive column.  Edited my original comment to include suggestion of dynamicSql and now provided a solution below.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit nasty, but hopefully this will work:

```
create table #result 
(
    schemaName sysname, tableName sysname, recordCount bigint, archiveCount bigint, sqlCommand nvarchar(max)
)
alter table #result add primary key clustered (schemaName, tableName)

insert #result (schemaName, tableName, recordCount, archiveCount, sqlCommand)
SELECT sc.name, ta.name, 0, 0, 'update r set sqlCommand=null, recordCount=cnt, archiveCount=arch from #result r inner join 
(select ' + quotename(sc.name,'''') + ' schemaName, ' + quotename(ta.name,'''') + ' tableName, count(1) cnt, count(case' +
   (SELECT
        ' when ' + QUOTENAME(c2.name) + ' = 1 then 1' 
        FROM sys.columns c2
        WHERE c2.object_id = ta.object_id
        and c2.name like '%Archive%'
        and c2.system_type_id = 56 --int
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
   ).value('.','varchar(max)')
   + ' else null end) arch from ' + QUOTENAME(sc.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ta.name) + ') x on x.schemaName=r.schemaName and x.tableName=r.tableName' 
FROM sys.tables ta
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc 
    ON sc.schema_id = ta.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON c.object_id = ta.object_id
WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 
and c.name like '%Archive%'
and c.system_type_id = 56 --select name, system_type_id from sys.types where name='int'
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.object_id,ta.name

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = sqlCommand from #result where sqlCommand is not null
while @sql is not null
begin
    print @sql
    exec(@sql)
    set @sql = null
    select @sql = sqlCommand from #result where sqlCommand is not null
end

select * from #result
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me start by saying Holy crap lol.  The column type is an int not a bit what's the type ID for that I can't find it in the system tables .

Comment: No worries - int is 56: `select name, system_type_id from sys.types where name='int'`